# Reusing range object in Excel.run for apps for office

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js, apps-for-office

I am new to APPS for OFFICE

I am trying a simple code in which I Validate Excel Data.
So Rather than nesting things in ctx.sync() again and again, I am writing code like this:-

```
        // **json** object used beneath is somewhat like:
        {"Field":[
            {"FieldName":"Field1", "FieldDesc":"Field 1 desc", "MappedTo":"B2", "IsMandatory":"true", "LOV":"1,2,3"}]}

       // **LOV** in above json data means:- the field data can only be among the values given.
       
        //********** MY PIECE OF CODE**************
       
        var fieldData = "";
        $.each(json, function (index, field) {
            range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange(field.MappedTo + ":" + field.MappedTo);
            range.load('text');
            ctx.sync();
            fieldData = range.text;

            if(field.IsMandatory == true && (fieldData == "" || fieldData == null))
            {
                headerValidation = headerValidation + "Data is required for Field : " + field.FieldDesc + "\n";
            }
            else if(field.LOV != "" )
            {
                if($.inArray(fieldData, field.LOV.split(',')) == -1)
                {
                    headerValidation = headerValidation + "Data not among LOV for Field : " + field.FieldDesc + "\n";
                }
            }

            range = null;
        });
```

As can be seen, I need to read range object again and again. So I am using range object everytime with different address and calling first "load()" and then  "ctx.sync()".

If i debug slowly , things do work fine but on running application i get frequent error now and then:-

> The property 'text' is not available. Before reading the property's
> value, call the load method on the containing object and call
> "context.sync()" on the associated request context.

Please guide me how I can handle this?
Also , is my approach correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of what's wrong, the error is next to your ctx.sync() statement.
You need it to be

```js
ctx.sync()
    .then(function() {
        fieldData = range.text;
        ...
    });
```

And I wouldn't forget the .catch(function(error) { ... }) at the end, either.

As far as reusing the variable or not, it really doesn't matter.  By doing "range = ctx.workbook...." you're actually creating a global range variable, which is considered bad practice.  Better to do "var range = ctx.workbook....".  And you don't need to worry about setting it to null at the end.

One thing to note is that since you're doing this in a for-each loop, note that the number of concurrent .sync()s that can be happening is limited (somewhere around 50-60, I believe).  So you may need to adjust your algorithm if you're going to have a large number of fields.

Finally, you can make this code much more efficient by simulataniously ceating all of your range objects, loading them all at once, and then doing a single ".sync".

```js
var ranges = [];
$.each(json, function (index, field) {
    var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange(field.MappedTo + ":" + field.MappedTo);
    range.load('text');
    ranges.push(range);
});
ctx.sync()
    .then(function() {
        // iterate through the read ranges and do something
    })
```

Hope this helps,

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Hey that was really really helpful. Thanks ..           What if i just need to write something to a cell only.  Say at cell B2, i want to write "XYZ". In that case i will make a range of B2 cell and set its Values property and call ctx.sync(). Thats it . Here i dont have anything to do in "then()" part. Right?

Comment: Correct, the "then" is only if you need to chain something in after the fact.  But you should still have a .catch, either there or somewhere further upstream if you're returning the promise.